# Direct inbound internet traffic to Function App through customer firewall that connects to vnet over expressroute

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Want to integrate Function App with inbound github webhooks. This inbound internet traffic normally would reach the Function App directly via a microsoft public url/ip. But company wants all inbound internet traffic to go through its firewall and then pass on to azure over expressroute.

If function app is on premium plan, it can be vnet integrated and now has a private ip. But for access to it from the Internet, I don't think I can simply access the app via a NAT using a new public ip address as I think Function App expects the url to use a specific host and domain name. Ideas?

Feels like the wrapper to the service is more complicated than the service itself.

Answer (score 0):

- VNet Integration doesn't grant inbound private access to the app from the Virtual Network but gives app access to resources in the same VNet.
- If you need to access resources through an ***ExpressRoute connection***, regional vNet Integration feature or an [App service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) is the only way, which runs in your Virtual Network.

> But company wants all inbound internet traffic to go through its firewall and then pass on to azure over expressroute.

- VNet Integration affects only outbound traffic from your app whereas inbound rules don't apply to your app in an NSG.
- To control inbound traffic to your app, use the ***Access Restrictions*** feature.

Refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration) for more information.